# global name 'getYearlyCost2' is not defined

Tags: python, ubuntu, global-variables, defined

I'm using python for the very first time and I am stuck on this stinking problem and cant for the life of me figure out why its not working. When I try and run my program I can get an answer for the yearly cost without the modification (even though its wrong and I dont know why) but not the yearly cost with the modification.

I've tried rewriting it in case I missed a colon/parenthesis/ect but that didnt work, I tried renaming it. And I tried taking it completely out (this is the only way I could get rid of that annoying error message)

## payoff file

```
from mpg import *

def main():
    driven,costg,costm,mpgbm,mpgam = getInfo(1,2,3,4,5)
    print("The number of miles driven in a year is",driven)
    print("The cost of gas is",costg)
    print("The cost of the modification is",costm)
    print("The MPG of the car before the modification is",mpgbm)
    print("The MPG of the car afrer the modification is",mpgam)

costWithout = getYearlyCost(1,2)
print("Yearly cost without the modification:", costWithout)

costWith = getYearlyCost2()
print("Yearly cost with the modification:", costWith)
```

While I know there is an error (most likely a lot of errors) in this I cant see it. Could someone please point it out to me and help me fix it?

Also I added my mpg.py in case the error is in there and not the payoff file.

```
def getInfo(driven,costg,costm,mpgbm,mpgam):
    driven = eval(input("enter number of miles driven per year: "))
    costg = eval(input("enter cost of a gallon of gas: "))
    costm = eval(input("enter the cost of modification: "))
    mpgbm = eval(input("eneter MPG of the car before the modification: "))
    mpgam = eval(input("enter MPG of the car after the modification: "))
    return driven,costg,costm,mpgbm,mpgam

def getYearlyCost(driven,costg):
    getYearlyCost = (driven / costg*12)
def getYealyCost2(driven,costm):
    getYearlyCost2 = (driven / costm*12)
    return getYearlyCost,getYearlyCost2

def gallons(x,y,z,x2,y2,z2):
    x = (driven/mpgbm)     # x= how many gallons are used in a year
    y = costg
    z = (x*y)               # z = how much money is spent on gas in year
    print("money spent on gas in year ",z)

    x2 = (driven/mpgam)     # x2 = how much money is spent with mod.
    z2 = (x2*y)
    y2 = (costm + z2)
                                                          1,1           Top
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's your immediate problem:

```
costWith = getYearlyCost2()
```

The function you're trying to call is named `getYealyCost2()` (no "r").

There are other problems that you'll find as soon as you fix that, such as no `return` statement in `getYearlyCost()` and trying to return the function `getYearlyCost()` in `getYearlyCost2()` and calling `getYearlyCost2()` without any arguments.

On top of that, `import *` is frowned upon, and then there's the use of `eval()`... but that'll do for starters.